# is:Read the line from file depending on condition

Tags: perl

I have the file with content:

```
Change sets:
  (0345) ---$User1 "test12"
    Component: (0465) "textfiles1"
    Modified: 14-Sep-2014 02:17 PM
    Changes:
      ---c- (0574) /<unresolved>/sha.txt
    Work items:
      (0466) 90516 "test defect
```

I want to read "90516" i.e the id  of the work item using perl and place it in an array.
Note: This is one entry and there can be multiple lines like this in file.
I want to capture all the work item ids like this and place it an array in perl.
code

```
$file = new IO::File;
$file->open("<sha.log") or die "Cannot open sha.log";
@file_list = <$file>;
$file->close;
my %seen;
foreach $line (@file_list) {
    #clear the array
    undef %seen;
    while ( $line =~ m/Work items:/g ) {
        @temp = split( /[:|,]/, $1 );
        #push the item to array only if no items in temp array i.e. if the occurance is for the first time
        next if $seen{ $temp[0] }++;
        push @work_items, $temp[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#open my $fh, '<', 'sha.log';
my $fh = \*DATA;

my @work_items;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( my $range = /Work items:/ ... !/^\s*\(\d+\) (\d+)/ ) {
        push @work_items, $1 if $range > 1 && $range !~ /E/;
    }
}

print "@work_items\n";

__DATA__
Change sets:
  (0345) ---$User1 "test12"
    Component: (0465) "textfiles1"
    Modified: 14-Sep-2014 02:17 PM
    Changes:
      ---c- (0574) /<unresolved>/sha.txt
    Work items:
      (0466) 90516 "test defect
      (0467) 90517 "test defect
Change sets:
  (0345) ---$User1 "test12"
    Component: (0465) "textfiles1"
    Modified: 14-Sep-2014 02:17 PM
    Changes:
      ---c- (0574) /<unresolved>/sha.txt
    Work items:
      (0468) 90518 "test defect
```

Outputs:

```
90516 90517 90518
```

Comment: what if I want to make the entry unique also in the array. There should be no duplicate work items into it.

Comment: [perlfaq4 - How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f)